# Why does my Python Websocket stop receiving messages but does not close? (On Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, linux, websocket, raspberry-pi2

I have a websocket client on a raspberry pi pinging a server as a keepalive using the ping frame.

The server occasionally sends messages to the pi (and responds to pings with pongs).

Sometimes I'll get a slew of pings/pongs all at once after a regular message has been sent.

I've left my pi overnight (several times) and it won't respond to messages from the server at all and the last pong received will be from the night before.

Any ideas why the python script on the pi stops responding?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using the Autobahn python library (Websocket, *not* WAMP)

Comment: Does your pi go to "sleep"?

Comment: @Myst I checked my pi this morning after allowing it to run all night. The logs were running pings all night from what I can tell. However, it didn't seem to drop the connection despite the fact the autoPingTimeout should have occurred.